# Classpath for Docker deployment

Tags: java, docker, java-8, classpath

Hello I have java application with this code.

```
@Value("#{'${data.location:classpath:/mydata}'}")
private File dataLocation;
```

When running in windows local its working fine, but when deployed in docker it cannot find the files specified in the classpath. Any idea?

Comment: How do you build your JAR/Docker image?